Sendgrid Domain Verification - DNS Propagation
I am trying go through Sendgrid's domain authentication process. I added the DNS records as required. However 2 of the records never seem to fully propagate.
image view of whatsmydns propagation checker where half of nameservers failed the query
Failed:
id XXXXXX
opcode QUERY
rcode NXDOMAIN
flags QR RD RA
;QUESTION
s1._domainkey.example.com. IN CNAME
;ANSWER
;AUTHORITY
_domainkey.example.com. 300 IN SOA xxxxx.xxxxxx.com. xxxxx.xxx.com. 1 3600 300 2419200 300
;ADDITIONAL

I have tried waiting more 48 hours for the records to eventually propagate, and tried re-adding the records.
